# Simulate a system of 2 coupled PDEs in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to solve two coupled PDEs of one time variable and two space variables with matlab? I have looked at PDEPE, but this only applies to one time and one space variable, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have the ["Partial Differential Equation Toolbox"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/index.html). Straight from the webpage, it says:

*You can use Partial Differential Equation Toolbox to solve PDEs from standard problems such as diffusion, heat transfer, structural mechanics, electrostatics, magnetostatics, and AC power electromagnetics, as well as **custom, coupled systems of PDEs**.*

Alternatively, you could consider using [FiPy](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/index.html), if you prefer Python.